# Unable to get AspNetCacheProfile to work in a WCF 4.0 service

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, caching

I have created a very basic WCF service application with the following code in the .svc file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace NamesService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class NamesService
    {
        List<string> Names = new List<string>();

        [OperationContract]
        [AspNetCacheProfile("CacheFor60Seconds")]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate="")]
        public List<string> GetAll()
        {
            return Names;
        }

        [OperationContract]
        public void Save(string name)
        {
            Names.Add(name);
        }
    }
 }
```

And the web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <outputCache enableOutputCache="true"/>
        <outputCacheSettings>
            <outputCacheProfiles>
                <add name="CacheFor60Seconds" location="Server" duration="60" varyByParam="" />
            </outputCacheProfiles>
        </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

As you can see the GetAll method has been decorated with the AspNetCacheProfile and the cacheProfileName refers to the "ChacheFor60Seconds" section of the web.config.

I run the following sequence in the WCF Test Client:

1) Call Save with the parameter "Fred"

2) Call GetAll -> "Fred" is returned, as expected.

3) Call Save with the parameter "Bob"

4) Call GetAll -> this time "Fred" and "Bob" are returned.

I was expecting only "Fred" to be returned on the second call to GetAll, because it should be returning the cached result from step (2).

I can't figure out what the problem is, so would be grateful for some help please.

Comment: Did not work for me either. Let me know if you happen to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cache the complete result without any parameter hence your setting should be

```
 <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="CacheFor60Seconds" location="Server" duration="60"
        varyByParam="none" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
 </outputCacheSettings>
```

**EDIT:**

```
[OperationContract]
[AspNetCacheProfile("CacheFor60Seconds")]
[WebGet]
public List<string> GetAll()
{
    return Names;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working.  I wonder if it is because I am using the WCF Test Client to test this?  Does caching work with the WCF Test Client?

Comment: No it should work anywhich ways..can you try  [OperationContract]
        [AspNetCacheProfile("CacheFor60Seconds")]
        [WebGet]
        public List<string> GetAll()
        {
            return Names;
        }

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the [WebGet(UriTemplate="")] to just [WebGet] but it is still not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your `web.config` configuration file has a double `<system.web>` section, try merging them.